# Why ajax call does not work on IE7

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am developing an app for a company i work for  but this ajax call only works on IE9+, FF, Chrome . I've been reading around without much luck.
Here is the code i have.It is pretty simple:

```
var request_getShoppingCart = $.ajax({
    url:"classes/sCart.php?action=getItems",
    cache: false,

});
request_getShoppingCart.done(function(Data) {
    $('#shoppingCart').html(Data);
});
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Likely the trailing comma after `cache: false`, IE generally doesn't like those.

Comment: Try to use `request_getShoppingCart.fail(function() {...}` to see if any ajax error is occurring or not.

Comment: Learn about JSLint or JSHint

Answer (score 4):

IE fails with `trailing comma`.

```
var request_getShoppingCart = $.ajax({
    url:"classes/sCart.php?action=getItems",
    cache: false //remove comma here

});
request_getShoppingCart.done(function(Data) {
    $('#shoppingCart').html(Data);
});
```

---

Also read

[jQuery .ajax method in IE7 & IE6 not working but working fine in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320090/jquery-ajax-method-in-ie7-ie6-not-working-but-working-fine-in-firefox)

[Does Internet Explorer 9 choke on extra commas at the end of array and object literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036618/does-internet-explorer-9-choke-on-extra-commas-at-the-end-of-array-and-object-li)

Comment: +1 This has been the bane of my existence since writing a load of jQuery plugins a while back, thinking it was a good idea to leave the trailing comma, so I don't have to think about adding it if I add more options.  Not so clever now!

Comment: Yup. It's fixed in IE8 and up. IE8 doesn't have the array fix (which wasn't a fix so much as a grey area in the spec they cleaned up in ES5), I *think* 9 does.

Comment: took out the comma and add a fail method. No errors occurs. I am using version 1.10.1 ashould i go back to an earlier version?

Comment: @user1960170 What **is** happening and what **should** happen?

Comment: Yes, IE9 has the array fix/change.

Comment: no data is returned from the call. If i use IE9 i get the data i am looking for.